# is it possible to have more than one active modules that are lazy loaded?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

We are working on a new project which will be tab based in UI level.the content of each tab will be a feature module and those will be loaded lazily. And there are provisions to keep multiple tabs and user can switch between the tabs. so, is it possible to keep already loaded lazy module active ? How should we keep router-outlets in this scenario ? And for eg: the lazy module loaded in tab1 will be persistent when tab1 is switched from tab2.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your implementation requirements.. the combination of lazy loaded modules, combined with persistent components is a hard one. The only option I can think of is combining multiple named router outlets in a single template, but that would make your routing very complicated and I’m not sure if that is lazy-loadable. I would look into lazy loaded components on template level instead..

Comment: @MikeOne thanks for the reply. i guess lazy loaded components are dynamically created components right ?

Comment: Yes correct. The issue with your approach is that if you load a component on a certain path (/bla/tab1) and you move to /bla/tab2 - the tab1 component WILL be destroyed and is therefore not persistent.

Answer (score 0):

So i have worked on this solution for a couple of days and i have zeroed in on a solution. We can lazy load a module manually without routing and have done a POC. And i hope this may help someone in the future and hence sharing the link here.

neo1380.github.io/lazy-loading